# Is it reasonable to downvote a question that 'could be googled' but isn't a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, question-quality

I know a lot of questions are just a waste of everyone's time but there are quite a few that get downvoted apparently for being too easy to answer. Is this a knee jerk reaction? Is it even common?

As long as it is a useful question and hasn't already been asked, what is the problem with asking an 'easy' question? Stack Overflow is a reputable source so if I see it in a set of search results I generally go there first. I often don't just want *an* answer but *the best* answer which Stack Exchange sites generally seem to provide thanks to the peer review. When programming I basically use google to get to Stack Overflow. So if a question I might ask google isn't on Stack Overflow I'd personally like it to be.

So should easy (can be googled) but unasked questions be encouraged?  Do a lot of people downvote them or is it just a vigilant few?

Comment: There might not be an existing question that asks what do _10 and 20 add up to_.  Would you like that to exist on StackOverflow? ____ Can it be easily answered?  Yes.  Would you downvote it?  _____  Would I downvote it?  Yes.

Comment: that's not a useful question though. I'm more talking about questions where the best answer might just be a link but the content is still useful.

Comment: _I'm more talking about questions where the best answer might just be a link but the content is still useful._ -- Based on what I understand, link only answers are supposed to be bad.  Period.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why that is

Comment: downvote tooltip says "does not show any research effort": if the question is easy to google, it fits

Comment: a link to another stable reputable website could make a good answer don't you think? safe to assume it will be valid for years.

Comment: You know what they say about assuming. But still, one could almost certainly make a reasonable answer by quoting relevant information from the linked resource. Still the answer to your question is yes, "This question does not show any research effort" is on the tooltip - doesn't mean you have to, but it's certainly reasonable to.

Comment: i agree with devnull on this. If there was no downvoting for simple questions it'd be just a "what is x + y" party. "How do i iterate lists?" RTFM really. I also downvote questions like "How do you validate a textbox for numbers only input" because it's just far too easy of a regex to research and there are plenty google answers on it.

Comment: @JonSkeet's [answer to *Are we begin "elitist"? Is there something wrong with that?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262447/643383) pretty much nails it for this question too.

Comment: I just suggest that downvoting should have a bottom line limit. Let's say -30 is the maximum. After that it reaches the bottom and will be frozen.

Comment: @Love Why?  What would that accomplish?

Comment: Though probably only relevant a fraction of the time, remember that what is easily found for one user may not be for another due to the [filter bubble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bubble). That is, Google may give me a great result in the #1 spot from my past searches but give a different result set to another user (especially one that doesn't have a history of searching for proper, related terms).

Comment: @cimmanon, I think that too many down votes discourage people. Personally I would like positive attribute.

Comment: "I'm more talking about questions where the best answer might just be a link but the content is still useful" What does that mean?  Can you give examples of such questions? If the question is anything like "Where can I find documentation for Python", it's going to get a downvote from me.

Comment: @Love You're missing the point.  Downvotes are supposed to be for lazy questions that show no real research effort (or are unintelligible).  Why shouldn't we discourage this?  If the asker doesn't like the fact that their question has been downvoted into oblivion, they are free to delete it.

Comment: I think we are finding more reasons why stack overflow is becoming less and less useful to ask questions on rather than use its existing q&a as a reference. When I ask a question i want the *best* answer that!= what some random guy of dubious credentials has raved about on a blog post and an army of sycophants linked to.

Comment: -1 you could have just googled it and found the answer yourself ;)

Comment: Effective use of Google is *hard*. Sometimes you don't know the proper terms to search for. I never knock anybody for that. And if a question gets closed as a duplicate, that leaves some new breadcrumbs for Google to find so that maybe the next confused person without the proper search terms finds an answer.

Comment: @Love Anyone that has an answer on < -30 and leaves it intact clearly isn't that bothered about downvotes as they could just succumb to peer pressure and delete it. Currently the lowest voted question on SO that is not deleted is on -29 so this would affect zero questions anyway.

Answer (score 51):

> Is it reasonable to downvote a question that 'could be googled' but isn't a duplicate?

Yes, it's what's expected of you:

[image: hover text with "does not show research effort" highlighted]

That said, there's obviously a continuum of questions googlable to a different degree, so you should always use common sense, and no one can force you to downvote.

Comment: -1: I have to agree with the original poster's intent here. It is far more important to me that a question is clear, has an objective answer and will be helpful to future visitors than whether it has been researched in depth. Super-easy questions should be discouraged, but other than that, I have no problem with well-written questions that potentially could have been answered with some more research first.

Comment: Besides that, in my experience, looks can be deceiving. I have two questions with negative scores, both of which look like they could have been answered with a quick Google search. But I spent 30-60 minutes researching each of them before posting.

Comment: @Kevin I think it comes down to a matter of degree. The tooltip says "does not show **any** research effort". (Emphasis added, obviously.) If a clear answer pops up as one of the first several links when you type the title or obvious search terms into your favorite search engine, then the OP probably did not do **any** research at all. Most SO questions can be answered with *enough* research, but we don't expect that. OTOH, we do expect at least *a little* research before asking.

Comment: @Kevin Strongly disagree. [**OP deleted post**] just popped up on SO. I don't even really *know* anything about Java; the first thing I did was Google "Java class relationships" and lo and behold, there were 50+ links to blogs and documentation and all of the info the OP needed was there. Then, someone *answered* the question (which didn't actually answer the question, ironically), and then deleted their answer. These types of questions shouldn't even exist...

Comment: While, I mostly agree with this, there are some cases where a poster may lack a **keyword** or terminology.  If they have used the *google phrase* in the question, then it is good to down vote.  However, be careful that what is obvious to you is not to the poster.  There are not always references on the internet that can tie concepts together.  Ie, you need a starting point for research.

Comment: @artlessnoise The OP in my example used all those keywords in his question. There is literally no way he could have failed a Google search, unless he typed *his whole question* into the Google search bar. I know where you're coming from though; sometimes I ask a question on SO that has been answered already simply because I didn't know how to search SO for it [lack of keyword/tag]. But there are some questions that show zero effort on the OP's part. When I ask a question, I at least try to make it worth others' time. My 5-second Google search got me the answer to his question, 50 times over.

Comment: Asking a question which could be Googled is not necessarily an indication that the asker has not put in research effort. It could be just they have Googled it but failed provide a good search query for whatever reason. I myself have suffered from that. The least useful response possible is an answer along the lines of 'Google it' - I have run too many Google searches which led me to questions whose only answers are 'Google it'. Made me want to scream. Better to answer the question anyway, the more positive Google hits the better.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but then after looking at the Help section it states the following which seems to contradict itself... "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to **every question about programming.**". I think "every question about programming" would include the easy ones along with the hard ones and everything in between.

Comment: @MattK Not every programming question is appropriate for SO.  For instance, we don't allow subjective questions (eg. which is best?).

Comment: @cimmanon, Understood I was just pointing out the contradictory statements... it says every question about programming **except x, and y, and z, etc.

Comment: "does not show any research effort" means to me that the question has already been answered or rejected on SO, and they didn't even bother to search for it HERE before a repost.  There are tons of questions on SO that have also been answered elsewhere on the internet.  They still make a contribution to the body of knowledge here.

Comment: so in other words if its on Google it must be right? Bring on the morphine because personally if that's the world we live in I don't want to care. I can probably find loads of terrible advice from people writing reactionary articles that arn't sufficiently scoped to their real intentions that would warp the mind of a noob (or someone who is not aware of the vast amount of religious fervor in software methodologies and their bastard offspring).

Comment: @JohnNicholas, that's where "googlable to a different degree" comes into play. It's completely different if Google easily returns an authoritative source like the official docs of a language/API, than if it returns some poorly written blog posts. OTOH, questions where methodology fervor *can* come into play tend to be opinion based...

Comment: To me, "does not show any research effort" shows up in how (possibly easy) questions are asked/answered. An easy question could for example be expanded upon by describing what was found so far and explaining why that wasn't conclusive. Or of course if a likely answer is known, OP can answer their own question.

Answer (score 12):

This depends very much on the question. The fact that Google can help find an answer to a question shouldn't be the sole criterion that makes a question good or bad.

The problem with Google is that it can yield a number of conflicting answers, some of them possibly misleading or plainly wrong. (One example is [a popular web programming site I shall refrain from naming by fear of increasing its SEO ranking](http://www.w3fools.com/), which for example has PHP+MySQL examples prone to SQL injection attacks.)

Considering how well SO has grown now, there are however very few simple questions for which you wouldn't be able to find an existing duplicate on SO.

This being said, "research effort" can be subjective. My main criteria are whether the question is clear, has sufficient details and is on topic. If there are grounds to provide a good answer to such a question (typically putting into context various conflicting pieces of information that could be found via a web search), I'd consider this a reasonable question. If I feel that the question (and answers, should some have already been posted) bring information that could be useful to other readers (and on topic), I don't downvote or vote to close, however "easy" I think it is (although there is indeed a threshold where it's obvious the asker has never attempted to learn any programming).

Thankfully, there are very few of these edge cases. For whatever reason, it seems questions that are bad because they're "too easy" or are candidates for "lack research effort" also tend to be correlated with the question that have bad grammar, poor formatting or along the lines of "fix this for me", in which case they deserve a downvote anyway (pending improvements, when possible).

Answer (score 6):

The amount of effort is the critical element here. In theory anything 'can be googled'. So the 'googleability' of a particular question I don't think sets a better standard than the actual standard, a question needs to "show any research effort".

Now when we read our existing standard I think the word "any" is very important. It sets a lower bar for research. Why? because the amount of effort required will dictate the breadth of coverage by the questions in Stack Overflow. So rather than stay on an abstract discussion lets add more meaning. Here are a few examples of 'googleable' questions.

- javascript test for undefined

The first result is actually the best result, Stack Overflow, but there are many other results that give us the right answer. The question was upvoted 465 times and is protected. The 'googleability' was not argued.

- concatenate strings in java

Again Stack Overflow at the top of the list. pretty much the same story as above.

- add two integers in c

Ok, that one did not make it, although I had to think hard to come up with such a simple question. Other good results from Google are available, it all looks fine to me.

- declare a variable in c

No results for Stack Overflow either, and I don't think there should be. Some blogs have the answer. It did suggest the next query

- declare a global variable in c++

Two questions from Stack Overflow, not a lot of votes on either but they weren't dismissed either.

Unless someone does a more thorough analysis. Stack Overflow users, don't really care about how relatively easy it is to find results elsewhere. But in the value of the question itself, and the bar is set low on purpose to create a wide pool of Q&A. There is no hard fast way to assess a question, it can be difficult at times but we have to apply our existing standards. I say the answer is no, we already have a good standard and it is not googleability.

Comment: The answer may not be in stackoverflow but in another place on the net like a blog entry. Also, *declare a variable in c* can be answered by reading a tutorial on C programming (which falls in a RTFM question).

Comment: blogs etc are temporary and transitory hence why link only answers are not approved of

Answer (score 3):

I spent about two months trying to find some information about "faceted search" before I knew the expression "faceted search" and before I knew the word "faceted" existed. Once I learned the right terms to use for the search I've found a lot of results but if I would have asked a question on SO it would have been downvoted. Remember kids, this is the Internet and you really don't know how much experience someone has or how old they are. New people are born everyday! :) and they need some help too. At least you can do is point them in the right direction (f.e. by putting a link to google with the right search terms).

Comment: Curious why you made this community wiki? There is no rep on meta anymore so if you were fearing downvotes this is a pointless preemptive defence!

Comment: So when you asked your question on SO, did you mention what you had searched for? It won't have included the keyword "faceted" but I would imagine you would have touched upon subjects closely related

Comment: @Sayse I didn't ask it on SO because I knew how people react to this kind of questions and I really didn't know anything about this field so the question would have sounded stupid for sure.

Comment: @MartinSmith You're thinking too much. I don't have enough rep to worry about it...

Answer (score 2):

As otus' answer points out, if a question does not show research effort then it is a candidate for a downvote. It also starts to creep towards another criterion mentioned in this tip text .. "not useful".

If an answer is readily available on google then all it is doing by creating another question that provides the same answer is increasing the number of results a search for the same question on google would return, it makes it harder to select a duplicate since there are more options to choose from, and it deters attention from other potentially useful questions.

IMO, the only questions that "could be googled" that don't deserve a downvote are those questions that mention their research effort within the question. This shows that they have thought about their problem and have yet to find a suitable answer

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of Stack Overflow as a one-stop-shop database. It would be nice to have access to all "Google-able" questions right here at "home". Duplicates can be a pain to wade through, but a nicely formatted, thoroughly covered answer for an easy Google "question" may not really be harmful. I'd much rather learn from here than go crawl a million separate UN-moderated web-blog tut's. ::shrug::

Answer (score -15):

Well its just the matter of opinion .

Let me say that no question is Good or Bad. 
A question is just asked in a wrong way or the user itself is not clear.If the question is Good then it's up voted  and Bad then either you down vote it or leave it.

I think that doing a down vote(without any proper dispute or reason you  are voting down) would be discouraging the user and senseless of the person doing it. Today if some question is hard for me ,tomorrow the same question would be easy which doesn't mean that I down vote the question as its easy or useless for me or others (this is the same question which was hard for me some time ago).

They are so many questions which Google alone cannot answer. Ex- you search code in Google it will give billions of results on Code . The fault is that the user hasn't entered a proper question.
Had the user entered Coding guidelines of Java then also he would get billions of results but with a difference.

The difference is that the user get's the correct result for the correct question he asked not for the wrong one.

Comment: "They are so many questions which Google alone cannot answer", but this discussion is specifically not about those. I will gladly discourage easily googlable questions - and hence encourage typing those questions into the google search box rather than our question form. If the question is good, then the question is good - googlable or not - but if the answer could be found with 5 minutes of googling, it's highly unlikely the poster spent any time formulating a decent question.

Comment: @OGHaza exactly .There are also some posts where they ask us  just to complete their task without any effort (They ask some question like How so and so thing can be done without any effort or code they tried) this kind of questions should be definitely voted down or flagged

Comment: +1. Not sure why this answer is downvoted to oblivion...

Comment: @FinalContest Because the poster didn't follow the cult of bullying and lamenting over any indication of even a slight shade of possibility that **someone** **somewhere** **might** be asking a question that well-thought. While I agree that there are lazy idiots who believe that getting an account on SO is equivalent to being a pro at work, most people are just not used to the way SO works. They need to be instructed and educated. Instead they're often bullied and put down.

Comment: Remember that voting on meta sites is a little different: it's less about whether a question or answer is useful and more about expressing agreement or disagreement. As I write this, this answer is at +6/-12, from which we can infer that roughly twice as many people disagree with the writer than agree.

Comment: I have no idea what can be so disagreed here...

Comment: @KonradViltersten: help center.

Comment: @borjab: do not get it. What is wrong with that, given that the OP explains the meaning of it?

Comment: Voting based on the quality of language is a really bad reason to downvote.

Comment: @FinalContest To clarify in case it wasn't clear. I do agree with you. I find it inappropriate that your answer has been so heavily put down. Happened to me to. Not much to care about - people are just  having bad day and like to bully.    :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: yes. :) Btw, it is not my answer. I just do not understand the non-constructivism ongoing with the OP. But on the other hand, the whole meta is fundamentally flawed. Useful discussions about the site should stay away from downvotes IMHO, but that is not how meta works, sadly.

Comment: @borjab: you have a weird idea about collaboration if you think people need punishment for their opinions. Come on, we are not here to punish anyone.

Comment: @borjab: that is unreasonable. If you think it is a truly bad post (which I do not agree with it), just downvote it. You should base your vote on the actual post rather than how others vote! But even that, punishment should have no place here. Hopefully, it is just bad word choice.

Comment: Thanks  all for the downvote/upvote this shows what kind of answers we can expect on SO

Comment: @FinalContest - I don't see downvotes on meta as being especially "punishing" as they don't affect rep in any way now. So people should just vote on whether they agree or disagree and not care about that as an issue. Likely many people read the first line "there is no such thing as a bad question" and decided they disagreed. On SO there are plenty of awful questions.