# Is there a problem with questions linked to on Meta recieving too much attention?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, meta

So in [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262583/what-should-be-done-if-the-asker-didnt-even-read-the-error), the asker linked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568076/java-lang-illegalstateexception-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child).

In one day, the question recieved *24* downvotes.

Sure it was a bad question, but most of the time, these kinds of questions get downvoted a couple of times, maybe answered, and closed.

Is there a problem with questions linked in Meta recieving too much attention?

Comment: It's often called the "Meta effect"

Comment: Sometimes it is only through being linked to from Meta that questions receive ***enough*** attention...

Comment: It can work both ways, posts have gotten many upvotes from the meta effect too.

Comment: try to rephrase the question to where it can be answered on a factual basis. right now, its primarily opinion based answers.

Comment: Bringing up a question on Meta naturally causes it to receive attention. Sometimes that attention is positive, sometimes it is negative. However, it always depends on the question itself, which makes this not a problem. (If the attention were always biased in some way or another, *that* would point to a problem.) As it stands now, if you don't want a question to receive any attention, then don't bring it up on Meta. (But ask yourself why you want to sweep the question under the rug.)

Comment: `Page not found.`

Comment: @Jamie It's been deleted...

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a well known problem called the ["meta effect"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204311/165773). The real question for me is if and how it can be avoided. When people ask about policies and behavior here, having links to specific examples really helps. So I don't think discouraging posters from linking questions is a good solution.

I think it's kind of questionable for readers of meta to downvote (or upvote) questions just because they happen to be linked here. But I can't think of a good way to stop it. Of course they will view the questions that are under discussion, and once they are there, they will vote on them.

You could imagine something relatively drastic where questions would be (temporarily) blocked from receiving votes while they are under active discussion on meta. But that doesn't sound quite right either. If you did that, the solution might be worse than the problem.

Comment: moderators sometimes (rather infrequently) use [content dispute lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127557/this-post-has-been-locked-while-disputes-about-its-content-are-being-resolved "example usage") to tame meta effect