# What should I do when someone downvoted my selfanswered question ignoring its value?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, self-answer, instant-self-answer

I have been reading through several SO *Q&A*s to find a general solution to a problem i faced without it being tailored to specific OP's needs.

I took the effort and created new Question, while as well providing, in my opinion, comprehensible Answer I devised during the process.

A user came by and argued that it's wrong. Suddenly a downvote appeared on my question. What should I do? I have seen this happening in SO, but there isn't yet a mechanism to counter that - or is there? *..or will there be?*
*(What would happen if I flagged the user's comments?)*

[The question in question is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29775469/985454)

**from FAQ:**

> ... to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

**A user comment:**

> If the users habitually award points based on anything apart from the usefulness of the questions and answers, the site will end up as a respository of... what?
>   ~[Earwicker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851/213889)

---

Potentially, would it be possible to flag dovnwotes for moderator's attention making the dovnwoters answer to an authority? **OR** what other kind of a mechanism would you suggest there should be to provide something to counter unreasonable downvotes?

---

#### edit

**I don't feel the flag is related.**
I am not concerned about losing two points. What I wanted to discuss is a the very principle of unreasonable downvoting and measures to avoid that.
Sorry for leading you astray.

Comment: Look at the question again to see if any improvements can be made, make them if you see any, and if not just move on and not worry about it?

Comment: You got *one* downvote.  That's not the end of the world.  They even explained why they downvoted, which is a rarity.

Comment: And maybe add a link to the definite meta-posts about self-answering in a acomment if that *really* seems the reason for the downvote. Keep in mind that all normal quality guidelines still apply. Anyway, stray votes happen.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I am obviously asking about a principle. That's what meta is for. This is happening to loads of questions and people here.

Comment: @Qwerty - loads of self-answered questions are getting downvoted?  Evidence, please.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It's not only about self-answered questions. Look at it from broader perspective. I don't care that I got -2 points. I care about a flaw in the system. There are people who obviously don't understand how it is supposed to work and give downvotes unreasonably.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for the link, however, it doesn't cover the principle I tried to point out. I wanted to focus on a mechanism to avoid that, rather than discuss my question being worthy.

Comment: In your comments on the original question, you say *"I have searched and read several Questions here in SO. I haven't found one which wasn't overly complicated or unclear"* - did you give any consideration to attempting to improve them prior to creating your own?

Comment: @jonrsharpe They were tailored to fit OP's needs and thus couldn't be edited in a reasonable manner. The other one, which is in the link provided wasn't known to me until I made my own Q&A, but then, the question is closed.

Comment: @Qwerty your *"principle"* refers to e.g. *"unreasonable downvotes"* and *"downvoted... ignoring its value"* (both **in your opinion**). Frankly, I just picked one - there has been endless discussion on [tag:down-votes] (see also e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262427/3001761) and the overall consensus seems to be that, bar the two cases I mention below, users are free to vote as their conscience dictates. Your opinion on the quality of that Q&A differs from theirs; that doesn't invalidate their vote. You got an explanation, too; count yourself lucky!

Comment: As the user who downvoted the linked question, here is my point of view. I downvoted the question in isolation. I downvoted the question because the explanation the OP gave for posting a new question for which answers are already present on the site was that he had to do a lot of digging to find the answer he was looking for. The right thing to do in such a scenario instead of posting a new question (in my opinion) is to 1) Edit the title of the existing question to make it easily searchable 2) Post their answer. I have nothing against self wikis that actually add value.

Comment: duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Potentially, would it be possible to flag dovnwotes for moderator's attention making the dovnwoters answer to an authority?

You really don't want us to have this capability. How could anyone possibly trust the voting system if a group of users could invalidate your votes if they didn't like them?

We can't even see who voted on a post. Even if we saw that, how could we know what their motivations were? Sometimes, [people vote because they lose their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Unless a large series of votes are clearly targeted from one individual towards another (in revenge or to defraud the system), people are free to vote how they want.

Comment: I understand that, thank you. Anyway, when I came to SO first I thought that high-rep users were all good and reasonable (later I understood the concept). You are right we don't want that.

Answer (score 8):

What can you do against a downvote on your question/answer? Nothing. People vote based on their own interpretation of what is a good question and what isn't. The best you can do is make sure that your question (or answer) is indeed a good question, and stop worrying about *one* user who downvoted your question.

If this doesn't convince you, you can always consider that the [highest voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/) on SO has 30-odds downvotes, compared to the 10k upvotes it received.

The system works. It won't be adapted to prevent a insignificant number of downvotes which aren't deserved. If you can't stand a single undeserved downvote on one of your question, you are in for a very rough ride on StackOverflow. This sort of things happen. The best you can do is not even think about it. As you said yourself, upvotes will come.

Comment: Funny fact indeed. So I take it that there won't be a mechanism countering this behaviour and people are just supposed to close eyes? Well, the upvotes will come eventually, that's for sure, but still. The principle...

Comment: What principle? This is a free website where people freely cast votes as they see fit. Everyting you post here, questions or answers, will be judged by the community, and will eventually receive downvotes, because... people, really. If you think it's unfair, then I don't think you'll enjoy your experience on SO.

Comment: @Qwerty what *"behaviour"*? Downvoting? No, there isn't a mechanism countering downvoting (except for: 1. sockpuppetry/vote fraud; and 2. block/revenge voting against a *user*, rather than *content*).

Comment: ARG I GOT DOWNVOTED. WHY YOU DO THIS TO ME? :D

Comment: @Laf Go raise your own meta post! :D (note that I actually upvoted you)